# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, activemodel

```
 In Gemfile:
protected_attributes x86-mingw32 was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
  activemodel (< 5.0, >= 4.0.0.beta) x86-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.4) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.4, which depends on
  activemodel (= 5.0.4) x86-mingw32

rails (~> 5.0.4) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 5.0.4, which depends on
  activemodel (= 5.0.4) x86-mingw32

web-console (>= 3.3.0) x86-mingw32 was resolved to 3.5.1, which depends on
  activemodel (>= 5.0) x86-mingw32
```

I already tried to do bundle, bundle install and bundle update but it doesnt work.

Comment: delete gemfile.lock? and bundle install again?, also could u share ur gemfile ?

Comment: what command are you trying to run?

Comment: Nop :(, i just tried and does not worked

Comment: bundle install.

Answer (score 3):

I made some research and turns out that the gem *protected_attributes* does not work with Rails 5, but the community made another that does work, this gem is *protected_attributes_continued*, so i just changed the gem in the *Gemfile*